# Can Cppcheck static code analyzer actually detect not very common warnings like "Relative Path Traversal (CWE-23)" or "Buffer Under-read(CWE-127)"?

Tags: c++, bash, static-analysis, cppcheck

I am working on [Juliet Test Suite](https://samate.nist.gov/SRD/around.php#juliet_documents) for my research and I am applying some Static Analyzer on these codes to generate warnings. After running `cppcheck`, I found out that it couldn't detect many errors mentioned in the `manifest.xml` file (metadata). Am I failing to run this software properly or cppcheck just can't detect these warnings/ errors? Have you faced them before?

I used cppchecker on the Juliet Test Suite till now. I am gonna use Clang, Veracode and Flawfinder on it as I failed on my first attempt.

This is the command I used.

```sh
cppcheck --enable=all -q --xml -I testcasesupport/ testcases/ 2>out.xml
```

In the given metadata `manifest.xml` file, some sample errors are -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container>
   <testcase>
     <file path="CWE127_Buffer_Underread__CWE839_connect_socket_01.c">
       <flaw line="111" name="CWE-127: Buffer Under-read"/>
     </file>
   </testcase>
   <testcase>
     <file path="CWE114_Process_Control__w32_char_connect_socket_03.c">
       <flaw line="124" name="CWE-114: Process Control"/>
     </file>
   </testcase>
   .
   .
   .
</container>
```

But my `output.xml` file generated by cppchecker doesn't have most of these errors. Most errors in `output.xml` file belongs to 'CWE-398' error which is a style error. But cppcheck can detect common errors like 'array-out-of-bound' or similar errors.

Is it that cppcheck doesn't cover these uncommon errors of Juliet Test Suite? If it is, what could be some other Static Analyzer that could detect them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cppcheck is fairly simplistic and far from perfect. It can detect *some* issues *some* of the time. But not all issues all of the time. Which goes for more or less any tool. But try out clang-tidy and the various sanitizers (asan, tsan, ubsan etc) in addition to cppcheck.

[Clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) is pretty good and free (see the [list of checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html)).

[Coverity](https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/static-analysis-sast.html) is the best I've ever used, but it's fairly expensive.

For runtime checking, [Address Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) , [Thread sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) and [Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) are all amazing.

And of course, always enable as many warnings as you can from your compiler and build both with and without optimizations enabled to catch different bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please suggest me some good Static Analyzers who work fairly good on Juliet Test Suite or other test suites with uncommon warnings based on your experience?

Comment: @ShamiulHasanRumman I already did, but I've added some links now as well.

Comment: @ShamiulHasanRumman > "Could you please suggest me some good Static Analyzers". Try PVS-Studio: https://www.viva64.com/en/cwe/

Comment: @AndreyKarpov PVS is worth a try, sure. But in *my* experience it is not really that good and has too many false positives. Although it may have improved since I last tested it 2 years ago. Coverity and clang-tidy have always seemed like the better options (to *me*).

Comment: @JesperJuhl "has too many false positives" - How to quickly check out interesting warnings given by the PVS-Studio analyzer for C and C++ code? - https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0633/

Answer (score 3):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

> Am I failing to run this software properly or cppcheck just can't detect these warnings/ errors? Have you faced them before?

To get an idea about what CWEs Cppcheck can detect you can use this command:

```
./cppcheck --errorlist
```

Look for "cwe" in the output.

> Is it that cppcheck doesn't cover these uncommon errors of Juliet Test Suite? If it is, what could be some other Static Analyzer that could detect them properly?

I do not remember what CWEs the Juliet test suite cover, but Cppcheck does not cover all CWEs. And I don't think any tool will cover all CWEs.

> cppcheck is fairly simplistic and far from perfect.

I agree. I believe in KISS principles. Cppcheck is far from perfect.

> But try out clang-tidy and the various sanitizers (asan, tsan, ubsan etc) in addition to cppcheck.

I agree. It is best practice to use several tools. This is best practice even if you use the most expensive tools (for instance NASA use various expensive tools and also Cppcheck because Cppcheck detects some problems those don't detect and vice versa).

> I am working on Juliet Test Suite for my research

In my opinion, the Juliet Test Suite is not well-made. The code is weird and unrealistic. Your conclusions will be of academic interest only. Run the tool(s) on real code.

I suggest that you scan some important open source projects. Cppcheck can find houndreds of thousands of bugs (undefined behavior) in Debian and this software is installed on millions of computers. The state of latest stable linux is not that good. :-(

Comment: Thank you for your well-written answer. And thank you for developing Cppcheck. It's really helpful. Is there some other well-written test suite which includes real-world buggy codes? I started with Juliet Test Suite. Later I found Itc-bugbench, Svcomp-benchmark datasets. As you are experienced, so I would like to ask you if there is any other good source or test suite of buggy codes. Actually, I need lots of data to train my model.

Comment: I can't recommend a good test suite. :-( We use debian to check how well Cppcheck works. We continuously analyse the Debian source code using latest development Cppcheck and latest released Cppcheck. If a new checker has been added we will study a set of Debian warnings. We can see that we don't have too much false positives, but we can't see exactly how many real bugs we fail to detect. We can compare the results of latest released Cppcheck and latest development Cppcheck and see if we have new false negatives/false positives. The reports are available here: http://cppcheck.osuosl.org:8000